# Rails: Socket Hijacking inside Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, reverse-proxy

I want to serve raw video streams with a rails application. I understood the best way to do this to hijack the socket and directly send my video stream (which comes from a remote location).
So basically a video reverse proxy.
Also i want this inside my application, to be able to apply logic. Otherwise i would just use nginx.
I am using `puma`.

I was able to this via `config.ru`, but i want it inside the application controller, to be able to use more logic and make the call to the remote more dynamic.

my config.ru:

```
map '/video' do
    io_lambda = lambda do |io|
    uri = URI("http://10.0.0.20/myvideo.ts")
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
      http.request request do |response|
        response.read_body do |chunk|
          io.write chunk
        end
      end
    end
  end

  app = lambda do |env|
    response_headers = {}
    response_headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'
    response_headers["Content-Type"] = "video/mp2t"
    response_headers["rack.hijack"] = io_lambda
    [200, response_headers, nil]
  end
  run app
end
```

putting the same in a method of the application controller does not work, i get an empty reply. I just added `:head ok` to circumvent an TemplateError and removed the `run app` line and the assignement the app variable.
I am quite new to rails and maybe i am approaching this the wrong way. Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated, as most ressources i can find are only for websockets.

I am also aware of this post: [Lightweight streaming HTTP proxy for Rack (Ruby CPU-light HTTP client library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668026/lightweight-streaming-http-proxy-for-rack-ruby-cpu-light-http-client-library) which pointed me in a good direction and was a lot a information to absorb and learn for me. The sendfile gem seems like the end solution, but i dont know how to hijack the socket and make the application controller just stream raw data to the client.

## Update 1:

- i found a solution with `ActionController::Live` that "works", but it reads all chunks of the remote file first, so there is a long client wait if the file is big.
  According to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.8/classes/ActionController/Live.html) it is able to stream data to the client as it’s written, but it reads all data first before writing. I see this from my debug output for every 1000 chunks, it fills up before the client gets any data.
  How can i serve to client passing chunks as the come in?

```
class SocketController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live
  def test
    i = 0
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4'
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
      http.request request do |remote_response|
        remote_response.read_body do |chunk|
          i += 1
          puts i if i % 1000 == 0
          response.stream.write chunk
        end
      end
    end
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem you are facing is that you are trying to use the `rack.hijack` header in an action in your Rails application controller. However, the rack.hijack header is only supported in the `config.ru` file.

To serve raw video streams with a Rails application, you can use the `sendfile` gem. The `sendfile` gem allows you to send a file directly to the client, without having to read it into memory first. This is ideal for serving large files, such as video streams.

To use the sendfile gem, you need to add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sendfile'
```

Then, you can use the `send_file` method in your Rails application controller to send the video stream to the client:

```
def stream_video
  send_file '/path/to/video.mp4', type: 'video/mp4'
end
```

The send_file method takes two arguments: the path to the file to send, and the content type of the file. In this case, the file is located at `/path/to/video.mp4` and the content type is `video/mp4`.

You can also use the `sendfile` gem to serve raw video streams from a remote location. To do this, you need to use the `Net::HTTP` library to download the video stream to your Rails application first. Then, you can use the `send_file` method to send the video stream to the client.

Here is an example of how to serve a raw video stream from a remote location:

```
def stream_video
  uri = URI('http://example.com/video.mp4')
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  send_file response.body, type: 'video/mp4'
end
```

This code first downloads the video stream from the remote location to a variable called response. Then, it uses the `send_file` method to send the video stream to the client.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank for you answer.
This answer is giving me some headaches, as `send_file` seems to be a method of `ActionController::Streaming` while the `sendfile` gem has a method `sendfile` without underscore, which works differently than your example. I was playing around with that before asking here, but it needs a hijacked socket to send data to.

Comment: Also opposed to `sendfile`, `send_file` takes only the `path` as argumunt not the content (here the `response.body`) itself. With your examples i get there the error `ArgumentError (path name contains null byte)`.

Comment: Indeed, I copied the code from an old project of mine, using an older version of the tool. I will try and check it on newer version

Comment: `send_data` from [ActionController::DataStreaming](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.8/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) takes the `response.body` as argument, but loads whole file into RAM and the client (a simple `mpv`) is not able to read the response.

Comment: I update my original post, as i got a solution with just the "little" part missing to serve the chunks as the come in.